# Why do some apps say they are free?

Tags: software-center

Why are there several programs in the Ubuntu software center that are labeled as "free", and then you go to install and you are prompted to "buy" a subscription to Ubuntu One? I appreciate all the guidance I continue to get from this community. Just a question.

Comment: *Your* definition.

Comment: This question was useful to me, and hopefully the answers will help someone else who may have the same misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's free as in free from restrictions. This does not necessarily mean free of cost.

This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre) may explain it better than I can.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes clicking the Buy button permits you to install the app for free and use it for a trial period (a month for example) before you have to decide whether you want to purchase the app in order to continue using it. During the trial period you can try the app without buying it. The Ubuntu Software Center prompts you to log in with Ubuntu One before you can install the app, so that Ubuntu One will have a record that you installed the app and the date when you installed it.

Comment: That makes sense.